# Alloc_chrdev_region don´t understand

Tags: linux, char, kernel, device

Please, help me out.

Why I must to pass "count of minor numbers" to this func. As I understand this func return MAJOR number, then I can use this MAJOR with mknod command with any minor number as I want. I'am right???

Answer (score 0):

The function reserves for you a range of minor numbers you can use to create different devices belonging to the same major number. For each minor number reserved you can create a different node (e.g. in /dev) by specifying the pair major-minor in mknod.
The minor number is one of the parameters the driver's "open" method receives, its typical usage is to distinguish between different device instances belonging to the same driver.

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe, for your reply. Then I have next question. If I reserve minor numbers from 0 to 4 and alloc_chrdev_region return MAJOR = 232 then ....................Can I invoke mknod with Major = 232 and Minor = 6 ????

Comment: No, the purpose of the function is to create a range of number suitable to create nodes (by the way, modern drivers automate the creation of nodes, you don't need to manually execute mknod - I suggest you to have a look to some of the drivers in corrent Linux source). Of course, you can do a mknod with any pair of major/minor, but it isn't much useful. mknod by itself lets you use any pair of major/minor, but when you try to access a node with wrong major/minor you get an error

Answer (score 0):

> As I understand this func return MAJOR number, then I can use this
>   MAJOR with mknod command with any minor number as I want. I'am
>   right???

You can always use any major and minor number, registered or not, with `mknod`; of course, the created device file is of not much use without an appropriate driver.

However, see [Linux Device Drivers, Major and Minor Numbers](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-3-sect-2):

> Modern Linux kernels allow multiple drivers to share major numbers...

After you successfully allocated a range of char device numbers, you could register another range with the same major, but different minor numbers; the kernel checks for overlapping minor ranges.